# How to achieve this python post and get?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I've been trying for hours using `requests` and `urllib`. I'm so lost, misunderstood by google too. Some tips, or even anything would be useful. Thank you.

Goals: Post country code and phone numbers, then get mobile carrier etc.
Problem: Not printing anything. Variable "name" prints out None.

```
def do_ccc(self): #Part of bigger class
    """Phone Number Scan"""
    #prefix=input("Phone Number Prefix:")
    #number=input("Phone Number: ")
    url=("https://freecarrierlookup.com/index.php")

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib
    data = {'cc' : "COUNTRY CODE", 
            'phonenum' : "PHONE NUMBER"}#.encode('ascii')
    data=json.dump(data,sys.stdout)

    page=urllib.request.urlopen(url, data)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    name=soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'col-sm-6 col-md-8'})
    #^^^# Test(should print phone number)
    print(name)
```

Comment: What is missing or not working?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters Im not getting any Information. Name ends up printing "None"

Comment: Are you submitting the string `COUNTRY CODE` and not an integer? Same for `PHONE NUMBER`

Comment: @MaximilianPeters No i am submitting real numbers, and my phone number too for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

As Zags pointed out, it is not a good idea to use a website and violate their terms of service, especially when the site of offers a cheap [API](http://www.data24-7.com/carrier24-7.php?r=1).

But answering your original question:

- You are using `json.loads` instead of `json.load` resulting in an empty an empty `data` object.
- If you look at the page, you will see that the URL for POST requests is different, `getcarrier.php` instead of `index.php`.
- You would also need to convert your `str` from `json.dumps` to `bytes` and even then the site will reject your calls, since a hidden token is added to each request submitted by the website to prevent automatic scraping.

Comment: Thanks, i found another solution that worked from the start. But this would of worked from your response. There are a lot of nice python apis that I would gladly pay for, but being 15 it isn't very easy to find a nice job ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with what you're code is trying to do.  freecarrierlookup.com is just a website.  In order to do what you want, you'd need to do web scraping, which is complicated, unmaintainable, and usually a violation of the site's terms of service.

What you need to do is find an API that provides the data you're looking for.  A good API will usually have either sample code or a Python library that you can use to make requests.